# Using adb on a Mac M2 (Silicon ARM Chip)

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, apple-silicon

I recently got a new Mac M2 from my employer. Now i installed Android Studio and wanted to run my Espresso and UIAutomator Tests for the android part of my kotlin multi platform app. But when i start the test, i always get the following message:

```
adb connection not available, or was terminated
```

When i looked inside the terminal and wrote:

`adb` i got this reply from my zsh:
`zsh: killed     adb`

Could it be that adb is not working on macs with apple silicon chips? Or did i forget to install something?
I installed the platform-tools once with Android Studio and, as this did not work, i uninstalled them with Android Studio again and installed them with homebrew.
Both installations had the same behaviour as described above.

I also tried to use Bash instead of ZSH, but the result was the same. the ADB process instantly got killed.

If you need any additional information, just ask.
I really hope that someone could help me.
Best regards.
Maverick

Comment: Adb works on Apple chips in general. So it must be a different problem. I use adb on an M1 Pro MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was not anything regarding a path, but a wrong policy in Cylance (a software my company uses to protect the computers).
After the correct policy was set, i only had to give Cylance full hd access to  actually save the new policy and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of

```
file /path/to/your/adb
```

includes

```
adb: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64]
```